# unlink() not working while I try to remove an image PHP

Tags: php, unlink

I am trying to remove an image from a directory using the `unlink()` function.

```
if (file_exists($oldPicture)) {
    unlink($oldPicture);
    echo 'Deleted old image';
} 
else {
    echo 'Image file does not exist';
}
```

The value of `$oldPicture` is `../images/50/56/picture.jpg`.

The follow block of code runs without any errors however when I check the directory the image is still there.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also use `var_dump();` and check folder/file permissions.

Comment: What is the absolute path to the php file being executed.  What is the absolute path to the "images/50/56/picture.jpg" path?

Comment: Probably that php doesn't have permission to delete the file.

Comment: as per your edit: even if you have permissions set on the folder, doesn't mean it has for the file, so check that and use error reporting as I stated above etc. - you've been given an answer below btw. try that

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah I am going to throw in that error reporting and see what it says, thanks. How would I use `var_dump()` to check folder/file permissions?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah everyone is right, I am getting denied permission...any idea how I can fix this? P.S. that error reporting is amazing, it will really help me thanks for that!

Comment: you're welcome. give me a few minutes; am on the phone. I'll come up with a solution for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no rush, thanks so much - I owe you a fancy cappuccino.

Comment: Yummy thanks! I posted an answer for you below. Let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"@Fred-ii- Yeah everyone is right, I am getting denied permission...any idea how I can fix this? P.S. that error reporting is amazing, it will really help me thanks for that! –  BigRabbit"*

Use **chmod** on the file before unlinking it:

```
if (file_exists($oldPicture)) {

// last resort setting
// chmod($oldPicture, 0777);
chmod($oldPicture, 0644);
    unlink($oldPicture);
    echo 'Deleted old image';
} 
else {
    echo 'Image file does not exist';
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

A last resort setting would be using `0777` as in the commented code.

---

> *"How would I use var_dump() to check folder/file permissions?"*

- It's not to check for permissions but to check what is being passed through that variable.

I.e.: `var_dump($oldPicture);`

```
if (file_exists($oldPicture)) {

var_dump($oldPicture);

// last resort setting
// chmod($oldPicture, 0777);
chmod($oldPicture, 0644);
    unlink($oldPicture);
    echo 'Deleted old image';
} 
else {
    echo 'Image file does not exist';
}
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Neither is working, should I assume that its not the files permissions but the directories? - I make this directory like this  `mkdir($directoryPath);`. Should I be making them like  `mkdir($directoryPath, 0775);`? As I am removing this image, I am also uploading another and I am also being denied permission (the error reporting is a godsend).

Comment: @BigRabbit yes  but chmod to 755 orr 777. **all** folders and sub-folders need to have proper permissions set. try and chmod 755 for the folders/sub-folders in your FTP program first, see what that says. As a "last" resort, you can set your folders to 777 but that's not safe. `mkdir($directoryPath);` does not set the folder's proper permissions. see the manual for it http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @BigRabbit Use `mkdir($directoryPath, 0775);` before you attempt in writing to it when uploading. You could also use the same method `chmod($New_Uploaded_Picture, 0644);` **after** the uploading code. I used `$New_Uploaded_Picture` as an example variable here.

Comment: Hmm k thanks, give me a bit and ill get back to you, just need to look over all of this and make sure I am understanding everything properly.

Comment: Would doing `chmod($anyNewPictureOrFile, 0644);` on any newly added image or file be a good a idea, is that a thing I should be doing or ..?

Comment: @BigRabbit yes, it's ok. Using 644 is safe and is the standard default on most servers.

Comment: Now that I understand `chmod()` `and mkdir()` a lot more I got it working. When I am creating new directories I am now doing `mkdir($directoryPath, 0775);`, also when I am uploading any images I run them through `chmod()`. After doing this, I was able to successfully use `unlink()` to remove images from the newly created directory.

Comment: @BigRabbit That's great news. So I take it with can wrap 'er up and mark as solved?

Comment: Also I will make use of `var_dump()` more often I see the benefits it has while debugging any issues. I will be sure to remove any error reporting during production. Thanks a lot Fred, I really appreciate all of this, I have learnt a lot today, game changer.

Comment: @BigRabbit You're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteDrFiles($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        array_map(function($value) {
            $this->deleteDrFiles($value);
            rmdir($value);
        },glob($path . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
        array_map('unlink', glob($path."/*"));
    }
}
```

Use the function like this

```
deleteDrFiles('../../uploads/img');
```

Comment: Please consider using the [edit] button and adding some explanation to your answer to make it more useful.

Comment: Relative file pathing is highly discouraged for PHP coding and should not be used here.